# What is the solution to the following quadratic equation in $\mathbb R$?

Tags: quadratics

$ x^2+\sqrt{d}x+d = 0 $ ,

Where $d$ is the real number whose integer part is $0$ and it's $n$-th decimal digit is given by (for $n>0$):

$ \text{NthDecimalDigit}(n) = \left \{ \begin{array}{l}0,\: \:\:  \text{if $2n+2$ can be expressed as the sum of two primes}\\ 
1, \:\: \: \text{otherwise.}
\end{array} \right.$

Obviously, the discriminant is -3d and d by definition is non-negative. Therefore, it holds that:

The equation has a real solution (x=0) if and only if d=0 (1)

But obviously, it also holds that:

d = 0 if and only if Goldbach's conjecture is true.

It is commonly stated that "the quadratic formula can solve every quadratic equation" (I provide a [proof](https://gbougioukas.wordpress.com/2016/10/23/quanoalg/) that this is not the case). Anyway, what do you think is the strict answer to the question of the title (some scientists consider equivalence (1) as a "solution")?

Comment: There is no equation…

Comment: Ops, I must make a correction. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$x^2 + px + q = 0$$ a quadratic equation then the discrimant is given by $\sqrt{\frac{p^2}{4} - q}$ so in your case it's $\sqrt{\frac{d}{4} - d}$

Because $d>0$ it holds $\frac{d}{4} - d < 0$ so your equation has no solution.

Comment: Can you prove that d>0?

Comment: It holds
$$d = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{10^n}$$ with $$a_n = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if $2n+2$ can be expressed as the sum of two primes}\\ 1 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

If you mean by "can be expressed as the sum of two primes" that two different primes are needed $a_1 = 1$ so $d \ge 0.1$.

If not your question depends on Goldbachs Conjecture… if he's right $d=0$ and your equation has one exact solution: $x=0$. If he's not right $d>0$.

Comment: Yes, it depends on the Goldbach's conjecture. So, you claim the solution of the equation is:  "if he's right d=0 and your equation has one exact solution: x=0. If he's not right d>0"

Comment: Edited my comment, was sent to early… but it doesn't matter: if $d=0$  you have one exact solution, if $d\not=0$ then $d>0$ and you have no solution…

Comment: You mean these material implications are solutions??

Comment: For your simple reformulation of Goldbachs conjecture… yeah :-)

Comment: So, you've just solved the Goldbach's conjecture :)